Within-subject analysis of the impact of energetic music on video game performance: Wilcoxon or Friedman?
I am conducting an amateur study of the impact of music on video game performance across multiple rounds of gameplay.
The gameplay loop is simple: Arrows are falling down, and you have to hit them at the right time with your keyboard (Think dance dance revolution), the game gets harder as it goes on for longer. A round of gameplay takes 120 seconds, and all rounds of gameplay follow the same pattern and gameplay loop. As such there is a strong learning curve that is logarithmic in nature.
A participant will play 4 rounds of gameplay, such that at first it is Either Music/No music, then No music/Music, then Music/No music then No music/music. Depending on the group they are in.
Now, all of my participants are split into two group at random. Apart from a between subject analysis, my mentor wants me to do a within subject analysis.
Now, considering all of that. Would you say, Wilcoxon test is more appropriate, such that I take all participants of a particular group, let's say group 1, and compare Round 1 (M) with Round 2 (NM), then Round 2 (NM) with Round 3 (M) and finally Round 3 (M) with Round 4 (NM). Or a Friedman test of R1,R2,R3 and R4?
And if so, why one over the other?
As i understand, Friedman test is when there are more than 1 parameters. But, is the learning curve considered a parameter? The transition between music to no music VS no music to music?
